# Finding intersection of arrays of strings or arraylist of strings in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

Is there any function for finding intersection of an array of strings or an arraylist of strings in Java?I dont want to use HashSet because I am bound to get a out of memory error.Since I have more than 10000 records.

Comment: Have you thought about using Sets?

Comment: More than 10000 records is no problem for a `HashSet`.  You'll need a lot more data than that to make memory a problem.

Comment: I have just tried using hashset but I got an out of memory error.

Comment: No the reason is that I am comparing list of files in two svn repositories.And at times there can be even 250000 files

Comment: 10000 is the least I am talking about.

Comment: Do the strings happen to already be sorted?

Answer (score 4):

java.util.Collection declares a [retainAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method that might be useful. I strongly suggest you familiarize yourself with that [java.util package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html), especially the [Collection interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). In fact, learning how to navigate and use the [Java APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) is a critical skill for every Java programmer.

However, I don't see that an `ArrayList` will give you an advantage over a `HashMap`. You will likely run into the same memory issues with either one.

Answer (score 0):

Any collection that dynamically allocates memory can cause an OutOfMemoryError. You simply need to assign enough maximum heap space to the program using the -Xmx flag.

After taking care of your heap size, you may find [Google Guava's](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries) [Sets#intersection(Set, Set)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v13.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#intersection%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29) method to be of use.